# Apache stop working. This site can’t be reached

Tags: apache, ubuntu, webserver, apache2

My apache web server goes down several moment ago. I have Ubuntu 14.04 on digitalocean with PHP 7. When I visit my site, it shows this:

> This site can’t be reached
>   crystalcrowd.ge refused to connect.

When I run `service apache2 restart` command, it Shows this:

```
 * Restarting web server apache2 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

last Error in the error_log:

```
[Thu Dec 08 08:55:41.970435 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 25213] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Dec 08 08:55:42.995218 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 30673] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Dec 08 08:55:42.995313 2016] [core:notice] [pid 30673] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Dec 08 08:58:17.074621 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 30673] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Dec 08 08:58:18.087459 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 30738] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Dec 08 08:58:18.087522 2016] [core:notice] [pid 30738] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Dec 08 09:28:16.914107 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 30738] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

Last moment I was trying to set up mail server.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting your server? That is the first thing to try.

Comment: crystalcrowd.ge is reachable now, so I guess you fixed it :)